# Get the name of the image with Jquery

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I have the following HTML :-

```
<li class="rpItem rpFirst d1">
   <a href="#" class="rpLink 1">
      <span class="rpOut"><img alt="" src="http://localhost:64034/Images/favorites_small.png" class="rpImage">
         <span class="rpExpandHandle"></span>
         <span class="rpText">Product1</span>
      </span>
   </a>
</li>
<li class="rpItem">
    <a href="#" class="rpLink 2">
       <span class="rpOut"><img alt="" src="Images/transparent.png" class="rpImage">
          <span class="rpExpandHandle"></span>
          <span class="rpText">Product2</span>
       </span>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="rpItem">
     <a href="#" class="rpLink 3">
     <span class="rpOut"><img alt="" src="Images/transparent.png" class="rpImage">
        <span class="rpExpandHandle"></span>
        <span class="rpText">Product3</span>
     </span>
     </a>
</li>
<li class="rpItem d1">
     <a href="#" class="rpLink 4">
     <span class="rpOut"><img alt="" src="Images/transparent.png" class="rpImage">
        <span class="rpExpandHandle"></span>
        <span class="rpText">Product4</span>
     </span>
     </a>
</li>
<li class="rpItem d1">
     <a href="#" class="rpLink 5">
     <span class="rpOut"><img alt="" src="Images/transparent.png" class="rpImage">
        <span class="rpExpandHandle"></span>
        <span class="rpText">Product5</span>
     </span>
     </a>
</li>
<li class="rpItem d1">
     <a href="#" class="rpLink 6">
     <span class="rpOut"><img alt="" src="Images/transparent.png" class="rpImage">
        <span class="rpExpandHandle"></span>
        <span class="rpText">Product6</span>
     </span>
     </a>
</li>
```

And I wish to target the first li, which has the `src="http://localhost:64034/Images/favorites_small.png"`.

So I wish to do something like

`if (imagename = favorites_small.png)`
then remove the click event from this item, ie not allowed to click.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('li img[src*=small.png]').each(function(){
    $(this).parents('a').contents().unwrap();
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/7MCKA/2/) is a working jsFiddle

**Source(s)**

[CSS Selectors](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/selectors_attribute.htm)
[jQuery API - .unwrap()](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/)
[jQuery API - .parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/)

Comment: Hi Billy, with your code I am managing to target the cell I want, however, the text is disappearing, and I am still able to get the click event

Comment: is your HTML structure the same as the one you posted above? And your jQuery code the same as mine? Because I use `.parent().unwrap()` it relies on these two conditions to work as you want it to.

Comment: [this](http://jsfiddle.net/7MCKA/2/) updated jsFiddle travels up the DOM tree untill it finds an anchor tag, then unwraps the contents.

Comment: well I posted the <li> part of the <ul>.  Should I post the full <ul> structure?  All the other <li> are very similar to the one I posted.  Tried your new code, still the same problem though

Comment: did you click update? I think this is the same as my one - it is working

Comment: Yes the link is ok, unclickable, but the image still is.  I have another piece of Jquery which is generating the image click, I have also added that in the new update:-  jsfiddle.net/7MCKA/4

Comment: See here: [http://jsfiddle.net/7MCKA/5/](http://jsfiddle.net/7MCKA/5/) I have added in `.not($('li img[src*=small]').parents('li'))` to your click function - this removes li's with the img from the set of matched elements before binding .on('click'

Comment: Billy that works yes!  I just need to know why the text is not appearing, most prob some css style.  What do these lines mean?         $('.rpItem').not($('li img[src*=small]').parents('li')).on("click", "img", function (e) {
and                 $(this).parents('.rpItem').addClass('noclick');
Thanks!

Comment: I also have another issue, since if the Item Title is favorites, I wish to have the ability to remove them from the list, so I do need a click there.  Please see my updated http://jsfiddle.net/7MCKA/6/ in the bottom JQuery part.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28244/discussion-between-billy-mathews-and-johann)

Comment: Hey Billy, will accept your answer since the requirements changed, and  I can use the same logic in the whole menu, ie removing and adding of items.

Comment: Ok - have another look at my last message in the chat if you haven't already

Comment: Ah did not know that the chat remains open :)  OK thanks a lot Billy!

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in one line with jQuery: `$('li img[src~=imagename]').unbind('click');`

Comment: I think it is the `<a>` tag that he is talking about with 'click'

Comment: @BillyMathews If so he should go for your solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
var imagesrc = $('selector img').attr('src');

var imagesrc1 = imagesrc.split("/") ;

var isize = imagesrc1.length;

var imagename = imagesrc1[isize-1];
```

By this you will get image name then you compare like.

if (imagename = favorites_small.png)